# How can the magnetic mirror force act along B direction if it is derived from $q\vec{v} \times \vec{B}$ force?

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

A typical derivation of the magnetic mirror force of a charged particle in a magnetic field such as from Nicholson (1983) pg 26 uses the $q \vec{v} \times \vec{B}$ force, conservation of the dipole moment $\mu$, and that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B}= 0$ to find the force acting parallel along a magnetic field is $-\mu \vec{\nabla}B$ which could also be thought of as a dipole in an external field has a potential energy U=$-\vec{\mu} \cdot \vec{B} = \mu B$ for gyromotion (electrons and positive ions) which if we conserve $\mu$ means $F = -\vec{\nabla}U=-\mu \vec{\nabla}B$ again but by definition $(q \vec{v} \times \vec{B})\cdot\vec{B}=0$ or it can't have a component in the parallel or local B direction. How can this be? This derivation is for a single test particle not an interacting self consistent distribution of plasma which ultimately must be why this doesn't make any sense. The dipole representation of individual charged particles gyrating along an external magnetic field line perturbs the local external magnetic field creating a force parallel to background field but not total field which is background + perturbation then right? It just seems wrong to say any force along the parallel or $\vec{B}$ direction comes from a $q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$ force right? Taking this a step farther from a multi fluid plasma perspective for a high conductivity (large magnetic Reynolds number =>frozen in) magnetically dominated ($\beta <<1$) anisotropic plasma how would one properly account for this magnetic mirror force in the momentum equation parallel to a field line? I've seen it included in the divergence of the pressure tensor in the parallel direction (RH Comfort 1988) but I feel as if it is proportional to the perp pressure but not coming from the pressure term as it is a volume force right? Final 2 questions: Wouldn't $(\vec{\nabla}\cdot \hat{P})_{\parallel}$ just be $\vec{\nabla}_{\parallel}P_{\parallel}$ and the magnetic mirror force density contribution to the parallel direction just be $n\langle\vec{F}_{mirror \parallel}\rangle =\dfrac{-P_\perp}{B} \nabla_\parallel B$? With $P_\perp = nT_{\perp}$ and $P_\parallel = nT_{\parallel}$ ($k_B=1$)

Comment: Think of it in one of the two following ways.  You can think of it being similar to a pressure gradient causing a force.  Or you can think of it as an time-varying electric field (i.e., due to the gyromotion of a particle moving into a spatially varying magnetic field).  The instantaneous Lorentz force causes the gyration, but the spatial gradient in the magnetic field introduces another force.